# Using __argc and __argv in MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

I was wondering, is there any nice way to use the builtins __argc and __argv (like in Visual C++) in MinGW (I'm including windows.h already), or will I have to do something more involved to access these parameters.  I'd so very much like to just have this code work in MinGW (but we don't always get what we wish for):

```
#include <windows.h>

extern int main(int argc, char* argv[]);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, INT)
{
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
```

Comment: Use `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` to retrieve the equivalent values.

Comment: Why the wide versions?

Comment: According to the literature I've seen, regular ANSI versions of those functions may not exist.

Answer (score 7):

These aren't "builtins," they are global variables provided by the C Runtime.  They are declared in `<stdlib.h>` in both the Visual C++ library headers and in [Stephan's MinGW distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).  If they aren't declared in your copy of `<stdlib.h>`, just declare them yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that particular distro.  Just for the sake of completeness, could you show me (or link me to somewhere that'll show me) how to declare them myself properly?  Thanks much!

Comment: @MaxFeldkamp perhaps using `extern`. Like in `extern char** argv;`. I did not get any messages about unresolved symbols with standard mingw.

Comment: I had a successful compile but a SEGV at runtime with `__argc` and `__argv`.  However, I was able to use `_argc` and `_argv` (one underscore rather than two) with no problems.